# Check if Invoice can be refunded online programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment, creditmemo, refund

Is it possible to check programmatically if an given invoice can be refunded online via a payment gateway like Paypal/Braintree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having a similar requirment my solution was to check the following:

- Can the invoice be refunded (`$invoice->canRefund()`)
- Does the invoice have an transaction id (`$invoice->getTransactionId()`)

Please note, that this doesn't verify if the gateway does support online refunds (e.g. Paypal/Braintree supports it)

I didn't find any other solution and I'm still open for alternatives.